# Does the child process in Node JS need to be killed manually?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, shutdown, spawn

I have a child process.

**The Questions is:**

- Does the child process need to be killed manually?
- Will the child process continue to run even if my application is shut down?
- Will the child process automatically killed if the main application dies?

**Example**

```js
import { spawn } from 'child_process'

const backTaskProcess = spawn(process.execPath, ['back-task.js'], {
  cwd: process.cwd(),
})

// Do i need to disabled it manually?
process.on('SIGQUIT', () => {
  backTaskProcess.kill('SIGQUIT')
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no, and yes. You don't need to kill it manually, unless you use [detached: true](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_detached) in the options. There are [exceptions when using fork()](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1790), but that doesn't apply to your code.